# Making Javascript array with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

So i'm making a google embedded page where i need some pinpoints declared.
I want to store these in a database and get them the way you'd also fill a table with php.

My code should produce this:

```
['Street', coordinates, coordinates, ID],
['Street', coordinates, coordinates, ID],
['Street', coordinates, coordinates, ID],
['Street', coordinates, coordinates, ID]
etc.
```

Right now i got this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
        <?php while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo '[' . $row2['Straat'] . ',' . $row2['Noorderbreedte'] . ',' . $row2['Westerlengte'] . ',' . $row2['ID'] . '],';
    }
        ?>
```

Can't workout how this should work or if there is an easier way to just get database objects via JS.

Comment: use `json_encode()` to transform php array to JS array

Comment: why don't you make a XHR request to get that that on page load instead of writing the object in HTML?

Comment: Well, i had no idea such thing existed.
But if you say it's easier. I might take a look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
// declare an array
$json_array = array();
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        // add this code
        $json_array[] = array(
            "{$row2['Straat']}",
            "{$row2['Noorderbreedte']}",
            "{$row2['Westerlengte']}",
            $row2['ID']
        );
        //echo '[' . $row2['Straat'] . ',' . $row2['Noorderbreedte'] . ',' . $row2['Westerlengte'] . ',' . $row2['ID'] . '],';
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($json_array);?>
```

Comment: Not yet, can I declare the PHP part in the javascript itself with php tags?
The database objects don't get displayed on the google maps

Comment: Okay, it picks up the array and places it now, except the first one.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to invent a wheel. `json_encode` function will do what you need:

**PHP**:

```
$locations = array();
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $locations[] = array(
        $row2['Straat'],
        $row2['Noorderbreedte'], 
        $row2['Westerlengte'],
        $row2['ID']
    );
}
```

**JS**:

```
var locations = <? echo json_encode($locations)?>;
```